# Magento2 remove index.php from frontend url

Tags: magento2

I have a magento2 based website and i am trying to get the index.php removed from the url. I have enabled mod_rewrite on the server and also enabled it via the magento admin panel.

In my virtual host file on the apache2 server i have the below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName testsite.islandtrinketz.com

    ServerAdmin ****@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/i******.com

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    <Directory /var/www/html/*****.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/****_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/****_access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

I also ran the below command in ssh and it says its enabled

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

So I am not sure why when I go to the site the only way a page will load is if i put index.php in the url manually?

Comment: Did you enable "Web Server Rewrites" in Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization?

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to Remove Index.php from URL in Magento:**

**For Magento 2:**

1. Log in to Admin panel
2. Navigate to Stores > Configuration > General > Web
3. Expand the Search Engine Optimization section
4. Set “yes” to Use Web Server Rewrites option.

[image]

5. Further, expand the Base URLs (Secure) section
6. Set “yes” to Use Secure URLs on Storefront

[image]

7.Save the configuration